# Detect Full HD on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone 8 app. I would like to detect full HD phones. I have read this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj206974(v=vs.105).aspx

Using the scaleFactor 720p and 1080p are in the same category. I would like to differentiate them.

I have also tried to use:

```
App.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth == 1080
```

But the value does not appear to be correct. What would be a clean way to detect full HD phones?

Comment: why `the value does not appear to be correct`? does it return value other than 1080

Answer (score 1):

Here's [**an article**](http://programmerpayback.com/2013/08/31/detecting-screen-resolution-in-windows-8-and-windows-phone-apps/) that explains a bit more on detecting the screen resolution for Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8.

Why your code won't work basically comes down to the fact that you didn't take the scaling into account. Following code (from the article) should solve this:

```
var content = Application.Current.Host.Content;
double scale = (double)content.ScaleFactor / 100;
int h = (int)Math.Ceiling(content.ActualHeight * scale);
int w = (int)Math.Ceiling(content.ActualWidth * scale);
Size resolution = new Size(w, h);
```

Now you can see if the width/height is equal to 1080. Hope this helps!

Comment: resolution returns 720x1280 on a 1080x1920 emulator.

Comment: If you debug this code, what are the values of `scale`, `content.ActualHeight` and `content.ActualWidth`? The latter two values *without* multiplying by `scale`.